# Can't Install Python Pandas in 3.6.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am Mac user and trying to install Pandas in Python 3.6.6. to use in IDLE / VS Code to do my work.

```
Hasans-MacBook-Pro:~ hasan-macbookpro$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.6
Hasans-MacBook-Pro:~ hasan-macbookpro$
```

But when i run the `pip install pandas` it download it in Python 2.7 as you can see below. When i go in IDLE since Pandas is not in 3.6.6. it give me error.

can anyone guide how to go about it?

```
Hasans-MacBook-Pro:~ hasan-macbookpro$ pip install pandas
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas) (2013.7)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pandas) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.12.0)
Hasans-MacBook-Pro:~ hasan-macbookpro$
```

Comment: Please accept the answer which worked for you. You should see a checkmark beside the answer. Click on it and it will become green indicating it has been accepted. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

try `pip3 install pandas` to specify it for python3.

Comment: Fine )) I guess you can close the question now